# On switching back to default content from frame, textarea data is getting erased in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Below is the html code**

```
<td id="ctl00_MainContent_UCApproverDecision_RadEditorContentCenter" class="reContentCell" style="height:100%;">
<label style="display:none;" for="ctl00_MainContent_UCApproverDecision_RadEditorContentContentHiddenTextarea">RadEditor hidden textarea</label>
<textarea id="ctl00_MainContent_UCApproverDecision_RadEditorContentContentHiddenTextarea" class="rfdRoundedCorners" style="display:none;" cols="20" rows="4" name="ctl00$MainContent$UCApproverDecision$RadEditorContent"/>
<iframe id="ctl00_MainContent_UCApproverDecision_RadEditorContent_contentIframe" frameborder="0" src="javascript:'<html></html>';" style="width: 100%; height: 453px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" title="Rich text editor with ID ctl00_MainContent_UCApproverDecision_RadEditorContent"></iframe>
</td>
```

**I used below code, using this i am able to enter the text. I verified in browser but on switching to default content textarea is getting blank.**

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(html/body)).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(html/body)).sendKeys("MyTESTData");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**What mistake i am doing here.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the correct HTML and is complete? The `TEXTAREA` tag is not inside the `IFRAME` and is styled `display:none` so it shouldn't be visible. Your code is clearing the `BODY` tag... which should not be correct. I'm not sure why this is working at all.

I would start with something like the below.

```
WebElement textarea = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea.rfdRoundedCorners"));
textarea.clear();
textarea.sendKeys("MyTESTData");
```

Comment: when i am trying according to your steps getting NoSuchElementOnWebPage. I am able to enter the text after switching into the frame. I want to know how i can switch back to main window without losing the text entered. May be i think i am able to enter the text using xpath=html/body because in iFrame tag u can see there is src="javascript:'<html></html>, which is resulting into a new html page within that iFrame.

Answer (score -1):

Frame #0 **is** the default content. If you want to address the first iFrame, you need to call `driver.switchTo().frame(1);`. But it's better to identify the target frame by its locator rather than the index number. Does it have an `id` attribute?

Comment: This is wrong, driver.switchTo().frame(0) will set the context on the first frame. Check the doc: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html

Comment: Exactly! And the first frame is the same as `.defaultContent()`, which is the base frame, so-to-speak. The first iFrame is accessed with `.frame(1)`. At least I'm 90% sure.

Comment: `defaultContent()` is not the same as `.frame(0)`. `defaultContent()` is the base page and `.frame(0)` is the first (0th) `iframe`.

Comment: Oops! Looks like you're right and I'm wrong. I've just recognized that on the page where I tested it, there is another iFrame *before* the one I switch to. So I'm indeed switching to the 2nd iframe using `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1)` without me noticing. But that's exactly why I prefer to find the iframe by Selenium locator rather than by index number: `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("myIframeId")))`